# Blender 2.92 Texture Baking black or very dark

Tags: texture-baking

Tried to bake a high Poly Asset to a low Poly Asset using Cycles. Face Orientation of both completely blue. Created Image Texture for the low poly and selected that one to be generated, and it is generating. However the output is either completely black, or a very dark representation of the high poly asset. For testing I have removed lighting and baked simple cube to another using diffuse with contribution set to color only (that worked). However in the wanted asset that baking process never succeds. Any suggestions?
Surely beginner issues I am facing but what is the secret of baking textures always successfully? My way obviously every each time causes new issues.

Settings so far:
Render Engine: Cycles
Bake Type: Diffuse/Combined
Contributions: Color on, Direct and Indirect off (also tried with on)
Material High Poly Mesh: Metallic 0, Specular 0 as well as Metallic 0.5 and Specular 0.5
Material Low Poly: same as High poly Mesh Material but an independent Copy. 

[image: High Poly]
[image: Low Poly]
[image: Bake Settings and Output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Texture Bake is Always a Black Square Even though I Unwrapped Everything I Need to Unwrap for Game Engine](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251964/texture-bake-is-always-a-black-square-even-though-i-unwrapped-everything-i-need)

Comment: You cannot bake the baking type *Diffuse* when you have set *Metallic* to `1` because metal has no diffuse color. Set the *Principled BSDF* node's *Metallic* slot to `0` while you bake the texture.